# How to print the result of $project in Mongodb in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, syntax

I currently have 3 mongodb collections that are in the following format:

```
collection = {
     "Link":link,
     "theAssociatedList":myList
}
```

Here is an example query where I provide a link and retrieve the associated list:

```
myquery = { "Link1": uri }
myd = firstCollection.find(myquery)
theOutputList= myd[0]["theAssociatedList"]
```

Where theOutputList is equal to [A1,A2,…,A3].

After querying all three collections, I receive lists [A1,A2,...,A3], [B1,B2,...,B3], and [C1,C2,...,C3] as output, given inputs, Link1, Link2, and Link3. I am trying to retrieve [A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3,...] in the same step as the query to save runtime.

I have the following code using mongodb to concatenate three arrays together and am trying to output `[A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3,...]`:

```
    nikeCollection.aggregate([{"$match": {
      "Link" : uriDict["Nike"]
    }},
    # adidasCollection
     {"$lookup": {
      "from": 'adidasCollection',
      "pipeline" : [{"$match" : {
      "Link" : uriDict["Adidas"]
    }}],
      "as": 'adidasCollection'
    }}, {"$lookup": {
      "from": 'newBalanceCollection',
      "pipeline" : [{"$match" : {
      "Link" : uriDict["NewBalance"]
    }}, {"$project" : {"theAssociatedList":1}}],
      "as": 'newBalanceCollection'
    }},

# Create 3 arrays
         {"$project": {
          "Link" : 1,
          "theAssociatedList1" : "$theAssociatedList",
          "theAssociatedList2" : { "$first" : "$adidasCollection.theAssociatedList" },
          "theAssociatedList3" : { "$first" : "$newBalanceCollection.theAssociatedList" }
        }},

         # Zip them in the needed order
        {"$project": {
          "Link" : 1,
          "theAssociatedList": {
           "$zip" : {
             "inputs" : ["$theAssociatedList1", "$theAssociatedList2","$theAssociatedList3"],
             "useLongestLength" : True
           }
          }
        }},
{"$project": {
          "Link" : 1,
          "theAssociatedList" : {"$concatArrays": [
                {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$theAssociatedList",0] },
                {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$theAssociatedList",1]},
                {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$theAssociatedList",2]}]
          }
        }}])

print(theAssociatedList)
```

However, when I try to print the result using print(theAssociatedList), it throws the exception:

```
print(theAssociatedList)
NameError: name 'theAssociatedList' is not defined
```

How do I simply print the associated list result? I am trying to implement this example: [MongoDB forum Q&A](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/one-output-given-3-inputs-for-3-different-collections/15503)

Comment: At which point are you actually calling mongodb? Can you include more of your code? Otherwise `theAssociatedList` clearly hasn't been defined in your example.

Comment: @sam Hi Sam, thank you for the response. I updated my post basically adding the information from my question I posted here https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/one-output-given-3-inputs-for-3-different-collections/15503/